# Slope of isoquants

Tags: production-function, producer-theory

Consider a production function $f(L,K)=\sqrt{KL}$.

The |MRTS|=$K/L$, and $\frac{d|MRTS|}{dl}=\frac{-K}{L^2}$

However, if I use the expression given in Nicholson and Snyder (Microeconomic Theory, Chapter 9 [Production Functions], equation 9.21):

[image]

and plug in values of the partial derivatives, then I get $-2K/L^2$.

I have checked the calculation twice so I don't think that's the issue. I have also checked with other functional forms and I get an extra constant in most cases. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Hi! Can you please refine your Nicholson and Snyder reference, so that it includes a subchapter name or something similarly identifiable.

Comment: I did the calculations for $f(K,L) = KL$ because the derivations are easier to do and I also get 
$$
\frac{f_k^2 \cdot 0 - 2 \cdot L \cdot K \cdot 1 + f_l^2 \cdot 0}{L^3} = -2\frac{K}{L^2}
\neq
-\frac{K}{L^2}
$$

Comment: @Giskard Updated the reference, it is equation 9.21 in the 10th edition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the key is that there are nuances in the notation, they are calculating a *full* derivative, not a *partial* derivative. They write between 9.19 and 9.20 that

> Because $f_l$ and $f_k$ are functions of both $k$ and $l$, we must be careful in taking the derivative of this expression

You write

> $\frac{d|MRTS|}{dl}=\frac{-K}{L^2}$

but actually if you are doing movement on an isoquant then $k$ is a function of $l$, and hence

$$
\frac{\partial|MRTS(k,l)|}{\partial l} = \frac{k}{l^2} 
$$
while
$$
\frac{d|MRTS(k,l)|}{dl} = 
\frac{\partial|MRTS(k,l)|}{\partial l} + \frac{\partial|MRTS(k,l)|}{\partial k}
\frac{\text{d}k}{\text{d}l}.
$$

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. As a corollary, if we want to show convexity of isoquants, we should show total derivative of MRTS (absolute value) to be negative right?

Comment: Yes. If you are looking at the total derivative, you are measuring change in MRTS while moving on the isoquant. If you are looking at the partial derivative, you are measuring change while moving in the positive $l$ direction (with no movement along the $k$ axis) from a point of the isoquant, so essentially you would be moving off the isoquant and would not really get any info about its slope/convexity.

Comment: Thank you. On a side note, I love your profile description: "leaving economics for something 'tangible'" resonates with me!

Comment: @AcadEconInd Thank you & good luck!